# WP-eComerce Advance Meta Tag data in descending order

Tags: custom-field, customization, e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am use [WP-Ecommerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) plugins for ecommerce support

Now i am set custom meta like this [image]

and it will display in ascending order like this
[image]

so i need to display it in descending order how can i do this?

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this inside the main loop you can do something like this:

```
    while ( wpsc_have_custom_meta() ) : wpsc_the_custom_meta();

    // Build an array of the custom meta data
    echo wpsc_custom_meta_name() .wpsc_custom_meta_value();

endwhile;
```